# Logical Issue in TicTacTOe

Tags: python

This is my tictactoe program for my final project in Computer Science. I self taught python this week for this program so excuse the horridness of my code. You can add any side length of a board and it will correctly create and allow you to play on that board. My problem is that howtowin:

```
howtowin = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))
```

Is hardcoded for a side of 3, which is a normal board. I need a method to take in the side length (num) and create an array of win combinations.

```
import math
def tic_tac_toe():
    board1 = []
    end = False
    howtowin = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))

def choose(): 
   global num
   num = input("How large do you want the grid? (input the SIDE length)")
   for a in range(num**2):
       board1.append(a)

def draw():
    x = num
    v = 0
    for a in range(x):
        print 
        for b in range(x):
            print(board1[v]),
            v = v + 1

def p1():
    n = choose_number()
    if board1[n] == 'X' or board1[n] == 'O':
        print("\nAre you stupid... Try again")
        p1()
    else:
        board1[n] = 'X'

def p2():
    n = choose_number()
    if board1[n] == 'X' or board1[n] == 'O':
        print("\nAre you stupid... Try again")
        p2()
    else:
        board1[n] = 'O'

def choose_number():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input())
            if a in board1:
                return a
            else:
                print("\nCan you not count to " + str(num**2) + "? Try again")
        except ValueError:
           print("\nI don't speak French! Try again")

def check_board():
    count = 0
    for a in howtowin:
        if board1[a[0]] == board1[a[1]] == board1[a[2]] == 'X':
            print("\nPlayer 1 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True

        if board1[a[0]] == board1[a[1]] == board1[a[2]] == 'O':
            print("\nPlayer 2 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
    for a in range(9):
        if board1[a] == 'X' or board1[a] == 'O':
            count += 1
        if count == 9:
            print("The game ends in a Tie\n")
            return True

choose()
while not end:
    draw()
    end = check_board()
    if end == True:
        break
    print("\n\nPlayer 1 choose where to place a 'X'")
    p1()
    print
    draw()
    end = check_board()
    if end == True:
        break
    print("\n\nPlayer 2 choose where to place a 'O'")
    p2()
    print

if raw_input("Play again (y/n)\n") == 'y':                                  
    print
    tic_tac_toe()
else:
    print("\nThanks for playing!!!!!!")

tic_tac_toe()
```

Comment: I like that you are honest enough to mention its your home work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your grid could look like this for a size of 5:

```
  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4
----+----+----+----+-----
  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9
----+----+----+----+-----
 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14
----+----+----+----+-----
 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19
----+----+----+----+-----
 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24
```

You can do this in several steps:

```
>>> size = 5
>>> rows = [tuple(range(i * size, (i + 1) * size)) for i in range(size)]
>>> rows
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)]
>>> cols = [tuple(range(i, size ** 2 * 1, size)) for i in range(size)]
>>> cols
[(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), (1, 6, 11, 16, 21), (2, 7, 12, 17, 22), (3, 8, 13, 18, 23), (4, 9, 14, 19, 24)]
>>> diags = [tuple(i * (size + 1) for i in range(size)),
             tuple(i * (size - 1) for i in range(1, size + 1))]
>>> diags
[(0, 6, 12, 18, 24), (4, 8, 12, 16, 20)]
```

Then you can aggregate rows, columns and diagonals:

```
>>> howtowin = tuple(rows + cols + diags)
>>> howtowin
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21, 22, 23, 24), (0, 5, 10, 15, 20), (1, 6, 11, 16, 21), (2, 7, 12, 17, 22), (3, 8, 13, 18, 23), (4, 9, 14, 19, 24), (0, 6, 12, 18, 24), (4, 8, 12, 16, 20))
```

This should work for any positive size.

---

please note:

- You did not know tuple but you were using them. In your original code, the `howtowin` variable actually is a tuple which contains several 3-items tuples.
- Tuples are effectively one-dimension array, but since you can put any iterable in tuple, you can use them as mutli-dimentional arrays. Exactly as lists.
- I used `tuple(...)` to obtain exactly the format you were already using but it was not necessary since you could use list as well.
- The main difference between lists and tuple is a tuple is immutable (=it cannot be modifed and any operation on it results in a new modified tuple) when you can modify a list.

The following code could be used exactly as you use the previous one. The only difference is that it uses lists instead of tuples:

```
>>> size = 5
>>> rows = [list(range(i * size, (i + 1) * size)) for i in range(size)]
>>> rows
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
>>> cols = [list(range(i, size ** 2 * 1, size)) for i in range(size)]
>>> cols
[[0, 5, 10, 15, 20], [1, 6, 11, 16, 21], [2, 7, 12, 17, 22], [3, 8, 13, 18, 23], [4, 9, 14, 19, 24]]
>>> diags = [list(i * (size + 1) for i in range(size)), list(i * (size - 1) for i in range(1, size + 1))]
>>> diags
[[0, 6, 12, 18, 24], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]
>>> howtowin = rows + cols + diags
>>> howtowin
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20], [1, 6, 11, 16, 21], [2, 7, 12, 17, 22], [3, 8, 13, 18, 23], [4, 9, 14, 19, 24], [0, 6, 12, 18, 24], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! I have never heard of a tuple before but from my understanding it is kind of like a 1-dimensional array. This was just what I needed to allow me to use all perfect squares. I'm now going to go edit check_board(), and I'm super excited to get this working!!

Comment: @ScrewLogics please give a look at the note i added about tuples and lists